# Angular 6 ERROR in Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/util/decorators from .../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts

Tags: angular6

I try to run the following to build my project for production and receive the error as stated in the subject:

```
ng build --prod
```

When I look in the core.d.ts file, it cannot find the following:

```
"./src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ";
"./src/profile/profile";
"./src/util/decorators";
```

The following is the entire file:

```
    /**
 * Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
 */
export * from "./index";
export {
  APPLICATION_MODULE_PROVIDERS as ɵangular_packages_core_core_l,
  _iterableDiffersFactory as ɵangular_packages_core_core_i,
  _keyValueDiffersFactory as ɵangular_packages_core_core_j,
  _localeFactory as ɵangular_packages_core_core_k
} from "./src/application_module";
export {
  _appIdRandomProviderFactory as ɵangular_packages_core_core_f
} from "./src/application_tokens";
export {
  DefaultIterableDifferFactory as ɵangular_packages_core_core_g
} from "./src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ";
export {
  DefaultKeyValueDifferFactory as ɵangular_packages_core_core_h
} from "./src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ";
export {
  ReflectiveInjector_ as ɵangular_packages_core_core_c
} from "./src/di/reflective_injector";
export {
  ReflectiveDependency as ɵangular_packages_core_core_d,
  resolveReflectiveProviders as ɵangular_packages_core_core_e
} from "./src/di/reflective_provider";
export {
  wtfEnabled as ɵangular_packages_core_core_m
} from "./src/profile/profile";
export {
  createScope as ɵangular_packages_core_core_o,
  detectWTF as ɵangular_packages_core_core_n,
  endTimeRange as ɵangular_packages_core_core_r,
  leave as ɵangular_packages_core_core_p,
  startTimeRange as ɵangular_packages_core_core_q
} from "./src/profile/wtf_impl";
export {
  getOrCreateChangeDetectorRef as ɵangular_packages_core_core_v,
  getOrCreateContainerRef as ɵangular_packages_core_core_y,
  getOrCreateElementRef as ɵangular_packages_core_core_x,
  getOrCreateInjectable as ɵangular_packages_core_core_w,
  getOrCreateNodeInjector as ɵangular_packages_core_core_u,
  getOrCreateTemplateRef as ɵangular_packages_core_core_z
} from "./src/render3/di";
export {
  bindingUpdated as ɵangular_packages_core_core_ba
} from "./src/render3/instructions";
export {
  loadInternal as ɵangular_packages_core_core_bb
} from "./src/render3/util";
export {
  makeParamDecorator as ɵangular_packages_core_core_a,
  makePropDecorator as ɵangular_packages_core_core_b
} from "./src/util/decorators";
export { _def as ɵangular_packages_core_core_s } from "./src/view/provider";
export {
  DebugContext as ɵangular_packages_core_core_t
} from "./src/view/types";
```

Do I run npm i decorators? If I run the following:

```
ng serve --disable-host-check
```

Correction to original post - now the project does not run at all. What happened? I have been testing this thing for over a month and, now that I am ready to go live, it just does not work at all after trying to create a dist directory. WTF?

The following is what I am seeing in the console:

```
TypeError: Class constructor Subject cannot be invoked without 'new'
at new EventEmitter (core.umd.js:3597)
at new NgZone (core.umd.js:3745)
at getNgZone (core.umd.js:4473)
at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.umd.js:4369)
at core.umd.js:4415
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at zone.js:872
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
```

When I run ng build I am seeing the following:

```
ng build --prod

Date: 2019-02-02T23:59:21.603Z
Hash: 51184dcdbc91f92a675d
Time: 3998ms
chunk {0} runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.42d170ae18051bd9f923.css (styles) 177 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.03b06938f23b8f1cb153.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.541dbdbf0b123b4c3be8.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/util/decorators from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/oshop/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts
```

BTW, now in app.module.ts, it cannot find module for HttpClientModule or HTTP_INTERCEPTORS

```
Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'
```

When I try to re-install @angular/common:

```
sudo npm i -g @angular/common^6.1.10
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@angular/common^6.1.10" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tam3/.npm/_logs/2019-02-03T02_29_27_361Z-debug.log
```

But it is in the package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
  "@angular/cli": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/common": "~6.1.10",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
```

WTF, I followed a post that suggested all I had to do was to trash the node_modules directory, followed by npm install and it would reinstall everything. What can I do? I literally was ready to go live today

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue, by solving various other issues, that I pointed out in another [post that I made on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500025/angular-6-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-open-users-username-npm-global/54521190#54521190)

First, I had to make sure that the npm(s) were no longer being installed in .npm-global, which I had done to get around no longer typing sudo before every/any install, but that came at a price, which I outline in the aforementioned post.

Second, I followed a couple of other posts on stackoverflow that instructed me to change my dependencies in the package.json file to the following:

```
"rxjs": "6.0.0",
"typescript": "^2.7.2",
```

Followed by deleting the node_modules directory, then do an npm install, but this only worked because my npm installs were no longer being installed in ~/.npm-global.

Also, as I stated in the other post, the build is still not working, but that is because there are so many other errors that I have to resolve going forward, but at least this issue is out of way and my system is back to where it was before this error popped up.

These are some of the errors moving forward that I am referring to:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
Property 'shoppingCart' does not exist on type {}
```