# Angular 6 illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/<username>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/

Tags: angular6

I followed a tutorial so that I would not have to use sudo before everything that I do with npm install

[tutorial to set npm global config to a new directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

No matter what I do, now it everything tries to install to this new ~/.npm-global directory. I have deleted it several times:

```
sudo rm -R .npm-global/
```

I tried to override the settings:

```
sudo npm set globalconfig ""
sudo npm set globalignorefile ""
```

But no matter what, if I try to run something like:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I still see it trying to install to .npm-global, followed by several warnings and it usually stops on the following:

```
ERR! path /Users/<username>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/atob/bin/atob.js
```

What can I do to get out of this nightmare? Please help

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is going through this, I thought I post what I found.

First, let me point out that I solved my issue, but it caused so many other issues, so tread carefully:

```
brew uninstall --force node
brew cleanup
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm 
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

Second, let me say that I have an older OS Yosemite, which brew no longer supports. As a result, the uninstall did remove node, but it also unlinked many links related to php and apache, which left me to have to re-install, configure, make, etc... manually just to get back to where I was before these errors started occurring.

This included downloading php 5.6.9 from php.net running config, make, install, which did not help things, because it over-wrote many config files, including my httpd.ssl.conf file, which will mention next. BTW, brew update said that everything was up to date. It would also warn me that brew no longer supports my operating system and this is why I had to install things manually.

Re-establishing my machine to where it was, included re-writing my httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files, which are definitely outside the scope of this post, but I thought I would warn whomever what you are in store for, if you should take this approach.

Also, after the config, make, install, I spent literally hours re-linking links using brew link - the following is a small list:

```
autoconf
automake
cloog-ppl015
composer
faac
ffmpeg
gdbm
gmp4
imagemagick
lame
libevent
libgpg-error
libksba
libmpc08
libtiff
libtool
libvo-aacenc
libyaml
mcrypt
mhash
mpfr2
mysql
nginx
ossp-uuid
pcre
php56
php56-http
php56-igbinary
php56-mcrypt
php56-memcache
php56-memcached
php56-mongo
php56-opcache
php56-propro
php56-raphf
php56-tidy
php56-xdebug
postgresql
ppl011
pv
python
unixodbc
x264
xvid
xz
```

I was able to find this list by doing brew update, followed by brew doctor. This was followed by typing the following commands to fix whatever errors apache was finding:

```
sudo apachectl restart
httpd -t
httpd -S
php --version
```

Once I dealt with all the errors of this and that module not loading, the system was back to where it was before the errors. The errors in question are posted on another post that I made to

[stackoverflow.com for not being able to do an ng build --prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499008/angular-6-error-in-couldnt-resolve-original-symbol-for-src-util-decorators-fr)

One more BTW, even though this is no longer an issue for me, there were plenty of other errors keeping ng from creating a build, such as Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement', Property 'shoppingCart' does not exist on type {}, etc..., but at least the app is fully functional, along with the PHP API that it posts to and that is a good starting point to deal with the remaining errors.

One other thing, with all the re-installs, I was receiving the following error from trying to connect to mysql:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

This turned out to be because other instances of mysql were running due to re-installs, as well as, when I tried to use MAMP to connect. I was able to resolve this issue by following the instructions in one of the answers of the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746484/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-35)

First, stop the server:
    mysqld stop

That is where I first understood that more than one process was running by the following repeated error:

```
2019-02-04 09:58:22 70222 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
2019-02-04 09:58:22 70222 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

Then find out what is running:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Followed by using kill  command (repeatedly) until the instance I needed was remaining, then mysql -u root -p worked